# Apache .htaccess <Directory not allowed here

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I run XAMPP and I'm trying to learn how .htaccess works. I have a file structure that looks something like this:

```
/parent
    /foo
    /bar
    .htaccess
```

I simply want to change all `foo` requests to `bar` with a GET parameter appended after them. For example:

```
foo/
foo/hello.php
```

turn into:

```
bar/?test=yes
bar/hello.php?test=yes
```

When I try to put the `<Directory>` directive in my .htaccess file:

```
<Directory "/foo">
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

I get the following error log:

> [Tue Sep 19 17:23:58.356362 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6336:tid 1900] [client ::1:60018] C:/xampp/htdocs/parent/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here

I checked my httpd.conf file and everything is alright. I'm sure because if I change the contents of the .htaccess file to simply:

```
Options -Indexes
```

It correctly displays a 403 error. If I replace the `-` with `+`, it shows the directory listing.

### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<Directory>` directive is not allowed in .htaccess and for meeting your requirements you don't even need this in .htaccess.

You can use this rule in site root (parent) `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I understand what the `RewriteRule` does and what the pattern in it matches, but can you explain what `RewriteCond` does? I can't understand what it checks.

Comment: `RewriteCond` uses a negation operator `!` at the start which means execute this rule only when `QUERY_STRING` doesn't already have `test=yes` query parameter. query parameter might be at the start, middle or in end. That is why I have `(?:^|&)` for start/middle and `(?:&|$)` for middle/end positions.

Answer (score 1):

`<Directory..` is not allowed in `.htaccess` according to [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory). You can have it only in server config and virtual host. You should use `mod_rewrite` instead.

Comment: Can you show an example? How would I implement that to solve my problem? The [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) gives examples with `<Directory>`. Maybe show an example solution to the problem in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Just delete the .htaccess file and your error.log problem will vanish.

Longer answer:

I started getting the same message in my C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log file earlier today.  The error began suddenly (after years of using localhost without a hitch) and coincided with a "500 server error" when I tried to start localhost.

The content of the .htcaccess file (which had appeared in my /Sites directory for the first time today) was:

```
<Directory>
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

As others have noted in relation to similar .htcaccess questions, the file is not generally necessary.

I therefore simply deleted the .htcaccess file, which instantly solved the problem.  Immediately localhost started working again, and the error vanished from the logs!