# How to run php mysql code in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Please check my error log and `.htaccess` file. My Cpanel does not support MySql code; it shows an Internal server 500 error. I think the problem is in the `.htaccess` file.

Error log file:

```
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:34.530795 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140489065998080] [client 49.207.9.94:64454] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:34.530687 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140489065998080] [client 49.207.9.94:64454] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:34.166873 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140489086977792] [client 49.207.9.94:64445] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:34.166703 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140489086977792] [client 49.207.9.94:64445] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:31.934927 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140489013548800] [client 49.207.9.94:64418] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:31.934809 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140489013548800] [client 49.207.9.94:64418] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:31.573282 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140489045018368] [client 49.207.9.94:64419] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:31.573169 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140489045018368] [client 49.207.9.94:64419] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:30.623233 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140488961099520] [client 49.207.9.94:63629] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:30.623046 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140488961099520] [client 49.207.9.94:63629] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:24.250987 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140488971589376] [client 49.207.9.94:63631] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:24.250817 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6050:tid 140488971589376] [client 49.207.9.94:63631] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:23.862360 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140488908650240] [client 49.207.9.94:63630] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:23.862232 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140488908650240] [client 49.207.9.94:63630] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:10.473825 2017] [core:alert] [pid 29732:tid 140489118447360] [client 49.207.9.94:62045] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:10.473729 2017] [core:alert] [pid 29732:tid 140489118447360] [client 49.207.9.94:62045] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:10.060590 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140488940119808] [client 49.207.9.94:62044] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:46:10.060428 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140488940119808] [client 49.207.9.94:62044] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:58.094999 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:60701] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:58.094846 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:60701] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:57.697276 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6237:tid 140489034528512] [client 49.207.9.94:60699] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:57.697173 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6237:tid 140489034528512] [client 49.207.9.94:60699] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:35.480760 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4318:tid 140489076487936] [client 49.207.9.94:58221] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:35.480635 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4318:tid 140489076487936] [client 49.207.9.94:58221] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:35.140764 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140488982079232] [client 49.207.9.94:57891] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:35.140654 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140488982079232] [client 49.207.9.94:57891] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:32.507857 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6237:tid 140488898160384] [client 49.207.9.94:57890] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:32.507706 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6237:tid 140488898160384] [client 49.207.9.94:57890] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:32.142869 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6236:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:57775] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:32.142728 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6236:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:57775] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:31.434755 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140489024038656] [client 49.207.9.94:57774] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:31.434625 2017] [core:alert] [pid 21299:tid 140489024038656] [client 49.207.9.94:57774] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:31.094164 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:57008] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:31.094051 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:57008] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:24.810721 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140488929629952] [client 49.207.9.94:57007] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:24.810528 2017] [core:alert] [pid 1602:tid 140488929629952] [client 49.207.9.94:57007] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:24.430768 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140488961099520] [client 49.207.9.94:57004] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:24.430628 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140488961099520] [client 49.207.9.94:57004] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:04.843597 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:54783] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:04.843468 2017] [core:alert] [pid 6191:tid 140488866690816] [client 49.207.9.94:54783] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:04.313624 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4318:tid 140489003058944] [client 49.207.9.94:54781] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 22:45:04.313480 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4318:tid 140489003058944] [client 49.207.9.94:54781] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 21:03:38.055866 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140489024038656] [client 183.83.247.92:9241] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css
[Thu Nov 09 21:03:38.055755 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4053:tid 140489024038656] [client 183.83.247.92:9241] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here, referer: http://houseofindiapa.com/css/jquery.bxslider.min.css
[Thu Nov 09 21:03:33.952440 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3524:tid 140489045018368] [client 183.83.247.92:9242] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 21:03:33.952319 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3524:tid 140489045018368] [client 183.83.247.92:9242] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your code **as text**.

Comment: please paste your code here....

Comment: The error logs says `<Directory not allowed` and your `.htaccess` does not seem to contain this text.  I surmise you are not really showing us your full `.htaccess`and vote to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing a connection instance to your `mysql_query()` function call.

Comment: write mysql_query()  function got same 500 error visible in my cpanel present in my cpanel .htaccesss file is empty is support apache service. anything write in .htaccess file please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is not writtent in right way, the column value must be specified like this when you use query with some reserved words or some special characters,

```
"INSERT INTO `mycart` (`customr_id`, `category`, `product`, `price`, `qty`, `output`, `status`) VALUES 
 ('0','0','0','0','1','0','0')"
```

Also, please ensure column names are correct.

If this does not resolves your problem, please post the error messages from cpanel.

As per your error logs, You need to remove Directory directive from .htaccess file.

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303236/apache-htaccess-directory-not-allowed-here) for reference.

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]
```

Use this code in .htaccess

Comment: same 500 error visible in my cpanel  present in my cpanel .htaccesss file is empty is support apache service.  anything write in .htaccess file please tell me

Comment: You are using Godaddy hosting if I am not wrong, Please follow this link https://in.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197 and check what exactly the error is.

Comment: [Thu Nov 09 20:02:58.748306 2017] [core:alert] [pid 18153:tid 140488982079232] [client 183.83.247.92:11523] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 20:02:58.748141 2017] [core:alert] [pid 18153:tid 140488982079232] [client 183.83.247.92:11523] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here

Comment: above message is my recent error log

Comment: [Thu Nov 09 20:02:58.748306 2017] [core:alert] [pid 18153:tid 140488982079232] [client 183.83.247.92:11523] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
[Thu Nov 09 20:02:58.748141 2017] [core:alert] [pid 18153:tid 140488982079232] [client 183.83.247.92:11523] /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here

Comment: Directory directive not allowed in .htaccess file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303236/apache-htaccess-directory-not-allowed-here. Please remove that directive.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: i have use above code in .htaccess file but not respond show 500 error please help sorry i am asking member to times

Comment: see this link  http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php

Comment: Hey, Can you please attache whole htaccess file and errors logs in another file, I can instantly answer you if you provide this

Comment: simple question sir i can use mysql code then show 500 error even i can write database connection code file is show 500 error only echo is show output

Comment: Please provide your code, .htaccess file and error logs file, Then only I could help

Comment: please check code

Comment: please provide your .htaccess file which is in document root

Comment: Document root is  /home/kaligotla1234/public_html/.htaccess

Comment: man, post all the code from htaccess file or attach the htacess file

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: this is my entire  .htaccess file  code                                                                                       
                                                                                                 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: this is my entire .htaccess file code

Comment: Why you are using this code, as per code I can see that foo is replaced with bar in redirection. So seems to be copied some test code and pasted here. Please commnet out the last two lines from .htaccess file and see if it works.

Comment: i dont know knowledge in .htaccess it is empty file you have give     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303236/apache-htaccess-directory-not-allowed-here  i have to update that code

Comment: last two lines means  this are  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ bar/$1?test=yes [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: Just delete .htaccess file

Comment: deleted  entire code show same error   http://houseofindiapa.com/submit.php

Comment: please send default .htaccess file

Comment: mAN, DELETE COMPLETE HTACCESS FILE not just code, remove the file from cpanel. If this still does not work, get support from Godaddy Helpdesk.